# SPD workflow to update List items at year-end

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a list of users, each user has some leaves allotted of different types(Say Paid, Sick, etc.).At year-end(31st of Dec) a workflow should run which will update all the leaves allotted to each user, Like:
1.  Remaining paid leaves should be added to newly allotted leaves(Remaining were 3 and allotted is 10 then allotted leaves for the following year should be 13)
2.  In any other leaves types, say sick leaves won't be carried forwarded only 10 days of leaves will be allotted.

Now, how should I achieve this, which type of workflow should I create, Site or List, and what steps I need to create in the workflow

Answer (score 0):

A list workflow. A SharePoint Designer 2013 style workflow.

Triggers on item being created. Starts a loop. Immediately goes asleep until the end of the year. Wakes and does the calculations. Repeats the loop. (i.e. never ends)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list workflow to do the calculations.

Then you can use PowerShell cmdlets to trigger the workflow, then use a scheduled windows task to call the PowerShell cmdlets. You can set the task trigger as the following:
[image]

About using task manager to call PowerShell cmdlets:
[How to: Run PowerShell Scripts from Task Scheduler](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/17736-run-powershell-scripts-from-task-scheduler)